# Mounting NFS Folder on to a Remote Machine (Both machines are on Red Hat Linux)

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, nfs

I'm a newbie to Linux and would need some advice on the thing I'm trying to achieve with regards to mounting a NFS Folder

I have a NFS Server: usanfsd01 
And a remote machine: usafssd01

I've a software installed on my remote machine "usafssdo1" and it takes the files that come into the NFS Server "usanfsd01" as input for execution so I'm thinking I should mount the NFS Server onto the remote machine. Please validate if my thinking is correct.

Also, if I mount the NFS Server on to remote machine using the following command, will it be a permanent mount

mount usanfsdo1:/home/files /home/mount/files

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

Mounting with "mount" command is not permanent only until the next reboot. If you need a permanent mount you have to edit "/etc/fstab" i.e.

```
usanfsdo1:/home/files /home/mount/files nfs rw 0 0
```